# Stop the progress bar animation when it reaches 100%?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a progress bar using jQuery and CSS. At the moment I have created the progress bar using CSS and I can animate it using jQuery. However, I can't stop the progress bar (loading animation) from stopping when it reaches the `100%`.

To explain the issue, I have created this working snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.progress-bar').css({
    'width': '0%'
  });

  setInterval(function() {
    // place this within dom ready function    
    if (currentProgress == '100') {
      alert('all downloaded');
    } else {
      var currentProgress = $(".progress-bar").width() / $('.progress-bar').parent().width() * 100;
      var setWidth = Number(currentProgress) + 25;
      if (currentProgress > 80) {
        $('.progress-bar').css({
          'width': '' + setWidth + '%',
          'background-color': '#86e01e'
        });
      } else {
        $('.progress-bar').css({
          'width': '' + setWidth + '%',
          'background-color': '#f27011'
        });
      }
    }
  }, 3000);

  // use setTimeout() to execute
  //setTimeout(showpanel, 3000);
});
```

```css
container {
  margin: 60px auto;
  width: 90%;
  text-align: center;
}

.container .progress {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
}

.progress {
  padding: 4px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05));
  transition: 0.4s linear;
  transition-property: width, background-color;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you run the snippet you will see that the progress bar keeps going even when it passes the 100%.

Can someone please advise on this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens when `currentProgress` is 90? :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6jvr0ahg/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your program didn't stop is you didn't stop the interval. Apart from it, there is a mistake in setting the width also.

I have attached an updated code based on your fiddle:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.progress-bar').css({
    'width': '0%'
  });


  var currentProgress = 0;
  var setWidth = 0;
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    // place this within dom ready function
    if (currentProgress >= 100) {
      alert('all downloaded');
      clearInterval(timer);
    } else {
      currentProgress = Math.round($(".progress-bar").width() / $('.progress-bar').parent().width() * 100);

      if (currentProgress > 70 && currentProgress <= 100) {
        $('.progress-bar').css({
          'width': '' + setWidth + '%',
          'background-color': '#86e01e'
        });

      } else if (currentProgress < 100) {
        $('.progress-bar').css({
          'width': '' + setWidth + '%',
          'background-color': '#f27011'
        });
      }

      setWidth = currentProgress + 25;
    }
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
container {
  margin: 60px auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.container .progress {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.progress {
  padding: 4px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05));
  transition: 0.4s linear;
  transition-property: width, background-color;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is modify your `setWidth` to be:

```
var setWidth = Number(currentProgress) > 75 ? 100 : Number(currentProgress) + 25;
```

now your bar will stop.

Your code is however not ideal. It is best to assign your setInterval to a variable so that you can stop it later like so:

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    // place this within dom ready function    
    if (currentProgress == '100') {
      alert('all downloaded');
    } else {
      var currentProgress = $(".progress-bar").width() / $('.progress-bar').parent().width() * 100;
      var setWidth = Number(currentProgress) > 75 ? 100 : Number(currentProgress) + 25;
      if (currentProgress > 80) {
        $('.progress-bar').css({
          'width': '' + setWidth + '%',
          'background-color': '#86e01e'
        });
      } else {
        $('.progress-bar').css({
          'width': '' + setWidth + '%',
          'background-color': '#f27011'
        });
      }
    }
  if (setWidth>=100){clearInterval(timer);}
  }, 3000);
```

Notice how I have assigned to a variable `timer` and used that as the argument for `clearInterval()`

Comment: Can you please create a FIDDLE with your second code in your answer? I'm struggling to make that one work!

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't produce the desired result: https://jsfiddle.net/6jvr0ahg/5/

Comment: I didn't include the first change i mentioned in the second bit. I've updated my answer and this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jeo7w8sL/1/

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`window.clearInterval(intervalID)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval), where `intervalID` is the result of [`window.setInterval(func, delay, ...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

Also, if you can help it (you can) use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) instead of setInterval!.